# How to hide the tool tips

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am having a treeview with some nodes. I am also having a panel. I have taken some usercontrol forms and i will load those usercontrols when corresponding node is selected from the child hood. Now what i need is  have some validations like if i left the text box empty i will have some tooltips displayed to the user. Suppose if i click on first node i will have a user control loaded. With out giving any values if i hit ok i will have some tool tips as follows
[image]

Now if i select the second node from the tree still the tooltips getting displayed i would like to hide those

[image]

Any Help please

---

my code for rasing error tooltips is as shown below

```
   public class TestClass
    {
        public void RequiredText(TextBox txtTemp, ToolTip newtoolTip)
        {

            if (txtTemp.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                txtTemp.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                newtoolTip.Hide(txtTemp);

            }
            else
            {
                txtTemp.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
                newtoolTip.Show("Required", txtTemp);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this was done in the use control form.

Comment: What type of control are you using for the error messages? ErrorProvider control?

Comment: No i am using tooltips as i shown in the image

Comment: Are the tooltips implemented through the use of the tooltip control as shown in the link I provided in my answer?

Comment: Ya actually i am having different tool tips for different user controls.

Comment: My sample code

public class TestClass
        {
            public void RequiredText(TextBox txtTemp, ToolTip newtoolTip)
            {
                if (txtTemp.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    txtTemp.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    newtoolTip.Hide(txtTemp);
                }
                else
                {
                    txtTemp.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
                    newtoolTip.Show("Required", txtTemp);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: This was implemented in almost all the usercontrols i am haiving and the one which was posted is my main form on that form i am loading the user controls as per the selected option from treeveiw

Comment: But not an mouse over. If i left it blank i  am validating it

Comment: It would be much clearer if you edited the code into your question rather than posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer just written Usrcntrl_Leave event for every user control as

```
    private void usrcntrlPPD_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

This solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet mastered the art of reverse-engineering code from a screenshot.  I'm guessing that you don't dispose the previous user control when you select a new one.  Allowing the tool tip to stay visible.  Use code like this:

```
    private UserControl currentView;

    public void SelectView(UserControl view) {
        if (currentView == view) return;
        if (currentView != null) currentView.Dispose();
        if (view != null) this.Controls.Add(view);
        currentView = view;
    }
```

And call SelectView() from the TreeView's AfterSelect event handler.

Comment: But the tooltips are not getting hided as per you said

Comment: You'll have to provide a minimum hint on how you display these tooltips.  I can only guess at you using the wrong Control argument in the ToolTip.Show() call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Hide method?

http://dotnetperls.com/tooltip

Comment: Hi but i am loading the usercontrol in a panel so how can i hide all those

Answer (score 0):

```
private void timer1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    if (count == 2)
    {
       toolTMensaje.SetToolTip(textBox1,"");
       toolTMensaje.Hide(textBox1);
       count = 0;
       timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```